# Excel 2010 creating a single list out of many

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to create a single list excel file that combines three others.

Basically we have three printers that independently keep track of copy/print usage for both black/white, and color. My main issue here is that the printers put out a list of names, but they are first,last in a single cell and also include other names which are not peoples names (admin, account exec, etc.).

What I want to do is sort through the non-people names (they have defined names so I could probably just name them in the exclusion) then paste the names of actual people in a separate sheet. From there I'm pretty familiar with text to columns function and I think all I would need to do is flip them around to get last,first.

I'm just not sure what function to use to sort through the names, or if that's even possible without tons of work.

Any ideas on how I could make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: What format are the lists you are copying from (excel, text)? Have you tried using advance filters?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Is this question about combining lists from three different sheets? Or is this question about parsing the items in a single list? Please clarify and please provide a data sample with a "before" and "after" scenario that you created manually.

Answer (score 0):

If the names are all separated by a comma then you could use Auto Filter, choose Text Filters, and Contains.. and type a comma. Then copy and paste the results.

Once you've combined all the different lists into a single list you can use the Data tab, **Remove Duplicates** option on this list.